# ondragstart on an array of elements dynamically in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas

I have an array of image elements,

```
var im = ["im1","im2"]; // from db or local drive
```

Then creating the images dynamically as:

```
var l = imagelist.length;
for (var i = 0; i < l; ++i) {
    if (i in im) {
    var s = im[i];

    var img = document.createElement("img");
    img.src = s;
    img.width = width;
    img.draggable = true;

    var body = document.getElementById("body");
    body.appendChild(img);

    this.addEventListener('ondragstart', function(event) {
        alert(event.target.id);
        event.dataTransfer.setData('text/plain', event.target.id);
    });

}
```

While the `ondragstart` event fires, but `alert(event.target.id);` shows blank.

That's the reason, the drag and drop functionality is not working for an array of images created dynamically .

Although tried dragging with a single image tag `<img>` which works absolutely fine, but the array of images doesn't work in this way.

Any solution for this?

Comment: What should `event.target.id` be? You haven't assigned an `id` anywhere.

Comment: Thats the target id where the image will be dropped , reference http://www.w3schools.com/Html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_draganddrop

Comment: You realize that `event.target` in the `ondragstart` event will be the item you're dragging, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't assigned an `id` to any of your elements.

Something like this should do the trick:

```
var img = document.createElement("img");
img.src = s;
img.id = "image_" + i;
// The rest of your assignments and code...
```